# How to embed Google Maps without google plus profile image?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

We all know Google+ no longer available but when I embed a google map at my website , It also try to fetch the google+ profile image at top right corner. As our company has zero tolerance for any error shows up at browser console, I need to fix that.

The error comes as

GET https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/s24-c/AAuE7mCCDDijtEQdXMHGnBHmUN6IEP9xAITbkdWWcdb1kQ 404

When I click inspect on chrome I found it is coming from :
`<img jstcache="90" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/s24-c/AAuE7mCCDDijtEQdXMHGnBHmUN6IEP9xAITbkdWWcdb1kQ">`

So the error is coming because the profile image no longer available as Google+ service halted. Need help to work around this issue.
I have embedded the map as:

`<iframe src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=241%20Canal%20St%2C%20New%20York%2C%20NY%2010013&t=&z=17&ie=UTF8&iwloc=&output=embed"  width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Comment: are you trying to get the URL of the image or remove it entirely?

Comment: there is no reason to get the url cause google+ no longer providing the service so yes I like to remove that image link completely. I have no idea why I am getting negative feedback here. Hopefully some one is good enough to answer this issue. I am pretty sure tons of users will get this error as many of us use embedded map at our contact us page.

Comment: but can you provide the code you're using to embed from goolgle maps? THere are many ways to do so and I would have to see your particular way to isolate the issue

Comment: @Yaakov5777 Thank you for giving time.  I have added the code <iframe>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only [legal] way to do this is to use the official [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) instead of embedding it from the iframe. You can check out the tutorial page, or search the web for many examples of how to mark specific addresses etc.

In order to use this you will need to [get a google API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key). With the new Google policy, you also have to enable a billing account for the API key to work.

Comment: looks like I am living in the past. Thanks mate your answer was helpful